# Выполнить скрипт, если checkbox checked

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как выполнить условие в js при checked? Есть несколько checkbox выводящихся из бд и у каждого свой value номер. Нужно составить скрипт: если один из активированных checkbox'ов имеет значение = 1, то выполнить document.getElementById("sub").remove();

Comment: Это несложно, но мне не хочется с нуля писать для Вас пример кода.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
let input_checkeds = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked');

input_checkeds.forEach(el_checked => {
  document.getElementById("sub").remove();
});
```

```css
#sub {padding: 10px; background: red;}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" value="one" name="checkbox input">1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="two" name="checkbox input">2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="three" name="checkbox input">3</label>

<div id="sub">#sub</div>
```

```js
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
let input_checkeds = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked');

input_checkeds.forEach(el_checked => {
  document.getElementById("sub").remove();
});
```

```css
#sub {padding: 10px; background: red;}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" value="one" name="checkbox input" checked>1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="two" name="checkbox input">2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="three" name="checkbox input">3</label>

<div id="sub">#sub</div>
```